# iPhone app crashes on adding UISwitch

Tags: iphone, ios, svn, crash, uiswitch

My iPhone app crashes when I add a `UISwitch` in xib. It crashes no matter on which view controller's view I add a `UISwitch`.

Interestingly... when i push that view controller, `initWithNibName` is called and app crashes before `viewDidLoad` is called!

The code is shared on SVN repo for team. I suspect the reason could be that project file may have been corrupted by the svn conflicts that someone was unable to resolve correctly. That's a possibility that I can think of but have no idea where to find the actual cause of this crash.

I need an expert advice on what are the possibilities of this crash, where to find the reason of a crash that occurs after the call of `initWithNibName` but before the call of `viewDidLoad`.

Thanks

Comment: One more thing, app crashes even if a UISwitch is added dynamically through code instead of adding it in xib.

Comment: Add the UISwitch from code but put that code in a try-catch statement and print out the exception your getting. That might give us more clues. To be fair , I can't think of a reason for the app to crash if ou add a UISwitch. Is the app running ok if you don't add the switch control??

Comment: Yes app is running ok if no UISwitch is added.
Let me check with a try-catch block, I'll let you know if any thing found

Comment: Regarding your SVN conflict suspicion, you should browse your repo's SVN history to see if there was a conflict recently and how it was resolved.

Comment: I've tried the try-catch...

Control enters in try block and crashes on UISwitch *aSwitch=[[UISwitch alloc] init];

Doesn't enter into catch block. When I run 'po aSwitch' on console I get "0x3656d717 does not appear to point to a valid object."

Answer (score 0):

please check  the name  that you  given in initialization  after initWithNibName and the XIB  name are equal.

for eg:

```
UIViewController *YourView = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
```

check that the name after initWithNibNme and the Name of XIB file are same

Comment: That's not the issue Mary. Also it is not crashing at a specific view controller but any controller if UISwitch is added. Doesn't crash if no UISwitch

Comment: try to add UISwitch programmatically